# React Native - How to get initial navigation state in React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to get initial state in the same format as onStateChange prop provides in NavigationContainer. onStateChange doesn't fire on initial render. In the example below, I managed to get state when navigating between screens, but not on the first one. Any ideas?

```
export default function App() {
  const [pageState, setPageState] = React.useState();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer onStateChange={(state) => setPageState(state)}>
      <RootNavigation />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the onReady method from the NavigationContainer
From the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container#onready

Comment: onReady method doesn't receive the state, how can I use it

Comment: Combine it with the getRootState method. You just need to add a reference to the NavigatorContainer. Something like this:

`const navigationRef = useRef()

const handleGetInitialState = () => { navigationRef.current?.getRootState() }

<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} onReady={handleGetInitialState}>...</NavigationContainer>`